# Add animation to netbeans-generated jFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm new to java and I'm trying to add an animation to a jFrame that I created using the Netbeans design editor. The idea is that there will be a background image and the animation will play on top of it. I'd also like to have other components that start out hidden and are displayed on top of the finished animation.

After some research on stackoverflow, I managed to create the animation I wanted. However, I can't figure out how to implement it into the Netbeans-generated jFrame I've created. As mainly a python user, all this method and class business is still a little confusing to me.

Here's my code for the animation:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AnimationTest extends JPanel{

int height = 1;

AnimationTest() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,618));
    ActionListener al = (ActionEvent ae) -> {
        repaint();
        if(height < 190) {
            height ++;
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(10,al);
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Color c = (Color.BLACK);
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillRect(0, 309 - height, 1000, 2*height);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame window = new JFrame("");
            window.getContentPane().add(new AnimationTest());
            createWindow(window);
        }
    });
}

public static void createWindow(JFrame window){
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

UPDATE: I tried replacing new JFrame with new AnimationFrame (the JFrame form I made using netbeans). Now the JFrame works but the JPanel isn't added (or isn't displayed). What is the right way to add the JPanel?

Comment: Your paintComponent should call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method on its first line, in order to erase old pixels. What problems specifically are you having with this code?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The code works fine for me. I'm trying to implement that animation into another jFrame that I created with the Netbeans design editor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: You've stumbled across one of (the many) issues of form editors. Instead, you can drag your AnimationTest class onto your netbeans form

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry, I'm still learning how to use Netbeans. How do I drag a class onto a form?

Comment: @JackBishop From the project view, drag the Java file onto the form

Comment: @MadProgrammer I got it working. Thanks so much for your help